# Title of books in Fahrenheit 451

Tags: fahrenheit451

At the end of Truffaut's Fahrenheit 451 we see Montag (Oskar Werner) learning by heart *Tales of Mystery & Imagination* by Edgar Allan Poe.

What book/novel does Clarisse (Julie Christie) choose to memorize? Is it said? We hear her reciting a few sentences (in French, in the link below), but I don't think the title of the book is ever mentioned.

The poetic final scenes, for reference: [Fahrenheit451 ending](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCaLf7fA07w)